# Epsilon-delta definition of uniform continuity proof

Tags: uniform-continuity

So I have my $x,y \in (0,1]$ and I have some $0<\alpha <1$.

I began my proof from here $|x^\alpha \ln(x)-y^\alpha \ln(y)|<|x\ln(x)-y\ln(y)|$ because we know $\alpha \in (0,1)$ so we have that $|x\ln(x)-y\ln(y)|\leq|x(\ln(x)-\ln(y))+\ln(y)(x-y)| \leq|x||\ln(1)-\ln(1)|+|\ln(1)||x-y|=0 < \epsilon$

And the $\leq|x||\ln(1)-\ln(1)|+|\ln(1)||x-y|$ holds because $x,y\in(0,1]$.

My question is I did not use my fact that $|x-y| <\delta$. I was wondering if my proof is wrong...? Or does this proof say something more stronger geometrically? Like it doesn't depend on any $\delta$? Or have I made a mistake in my proof?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Well you seem to have reached the conclusion that $\left|x \ln x - y \ln y\right| \le 0$. But this is not generally true (it is only true  if $x\ln x = y\ln y$, which only happens if $x=y$, for $x,y\in (0,1]$). You can't just say $$\color{red}{|x(\ln(x)-\ln(y))+\ln(y)(x-y)| \leq|x||\ln(1)-\ln(1)|+|\ln(1)||x-y|}$$ (in fact this is untrue).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you made a mistake. Firs of all, it is not obvious why should we have$$|x^\alpha \ln(x)-y^\alpha \ln(y)|<|x\ln(x)-y\ln(y)|.$$And if it was true that we always have $|x\ln(x)-y\ln(y)|\leqslant0$, then the conclusion would be that the map $x\mapsto x\ln(x)$ would be constant, which obviously is not true.

You can prove that your map (let us call it $f$) is uniformly continuous noting that $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$. So, you can extend it to a continuous map from $[0,1]$ in $\mathbb R$. But every continuous map defined on a closed and bounded interval is uniformly continuous.